# Sonata Admin Bundle - Custom Template

Tags: php, templates, bundle, sonata

I want to custome my template.

service.yml :

```
admin.globaux:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\ParametreAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\ParametreEntity, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Options, label: Globaux}
        calls:
            - [ setTemplate, [list, "@SonataAdmin/CRUD/Special/list_parametre_globaux.html.twig"]]
        public: true
```

list_parametre_globaux.html.twig :

```
{% extends base_template %}

    <div>
        {{ object.pourcentageMise }}
    </div>
```

I have this error :

(1/1) ServiceNotFoundException
The service "admin.globaux" has a dependency on a non-existent service "SonataAdmin/CRUD/Special/list_parametre_globaux.html.twig".

I don't understand why it doesnt work.

thank for your help

Comment: which sonata admin version you are using?

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to call a service, that's what your message error says.

```
calls:
    - [ setTemplate, [list, "@SonataAdmin/CRUD/Special/list_parametre_globaux.html.twig"]]
```

The "@" syntax is designed for service injection.

This is how you should write your template call:

```
calls:
    - [ setTemplate, [list, "SonataAdminBundle:CRUD/Special:list_parametre_globaux.html.twig"]]
```

That means that your custom template is located in

```
vendor/sonata-admin/admin-bundle/Resources/views/CRUD/Special/list_parametre_globaux.html.twig
```

It is not a good idea to put files in vendor folder, you should put it in

```
src/AppBundle/Resources/views/CRUD/Special/list_parametre_globaux.html.twig
```

Then your template call in your service.yml would be

```
calls:
    - [ setTemplate, [list, "AppBundle:CRUD/Special:list_parametre_globaux.html.twig"]]
```

Also, in the file `list_parametre_globaux.html.twig`, you shouldn't

```
{% extends base_template %}
```

But

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list.html.twig' %}
```

This is the twig template used for list action.
If you check the original template located in

```
vendor/sonata-admin/admin-bundle/Resources/views/CRUD/base_list.html.twig
```

you'll see different blocks. You can override each block by writting some code inside this in your custom twig template.

```
{% block name_of_block %}
{% endblock name_of_block}
```

If you just want to add thing but not override the whole block, you can do it like that

```
{% block name_of_block %}
    enter code here
    {{parent ()}}
{% endblock name_of_block}
```

At last, if you want to override just a part of the block, then you'll have to copy/paste the whole base_block in your custom twig template, and rewrite the specific parts.